# Draw points 1 size bigger than the line size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to draw a plot in `ggplot` using `stat_summary()` with `geom="line"` and `geom="point"`

For that I use the following function:

```
drawPlot <- function(...) ggplot2::ggplot(...) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line" ) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point" ) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(0.5, 0.8, 1.2, 2, 3, 4, 5) )
```

With this function when I do:

```
drawPlot(data = metric_sum, aes(x = x_metric, y=summedValue, size=as.factor(clusteringDistance)))
```

I get a plot which has lines with different sizes, and no points at all.

---

Instead I would like to have a plot where the lines would have dots as well, and those dots would be 1 size bigger than the line itself, so they are noticeable.

I believe this could be achieved by drawing each plot separately (not using the `drawPlot` function) and doing `aes` for the `stat_summary(geom="point")`.

Is is possible to achieve the same within the `drawPlot` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points are being plotted, but they are the same color and size as the lines, so you can't see them. You can see this in the following example with your code slightly altered to use the built-in `mtcars` data frame. The lines and points are plotted in different colors and the points are now visible:

```
drawPlot <- function(...) ggplot2::ggplot(...) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", colour="grey40") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", colour="yellow") +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1:3) ) 

drawPlot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg, size=as.factor(gear)))
```

[image]

I don't know if there's a way to set the line and point sizes in two separate aesthetic mappings, since they're both keyed to the same aesthetic. But here's a quick hack that might at least get you started in the direction you want to go:

`gear` has three levels. So, in the call to `geom_point` we add 3 to the value of gear before turning it into a factor. That effectively adds three new levels to `gear` in the plot, for a total of six levels. The first three levels apply to the lines, and the next three levels apply to the points. We can then set their sizes independently in the call to `scale_size_manual`. (That messes up the legend, but I'm not sure how to deal with that without resorting to lower-level `grid` functions.)

```
drawPlot2 <- function(...) ggplot2::ggplot(...) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(size=factor(gear)), colour="grey40") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", aes(size=factor(gear + 3)), 
               pch=21, fill="yellow", colour="black") +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1,1.5,2,2,3,4)) 

drawPlot2(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg))
```

[image]

Comment: terrific answer! except that it destroys my legend, otherwise perfect!